# Simple createElement issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I thought the following script will create div element but I got nothing output in my html. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot.

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id','testttttttt');

div.innerHTML='fjsoidfjiosdjfoi';​
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This is what I got when using Jquery too much and forget about all the basis in javascript...lol  +1 all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `appendChild` method in the end:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id','testttttttt');
div.innerHTML='fjsoidfjiosdjfoi';​
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Otherwise, the created element will exist, but won't appear in your page.

Also, you have to be sure that `document.body` exists, otherwise, it will throw an error (if this script is going to be executed when loaded, put it inside an `onload` event).

PS: You can also append to any other DOM elements:

```
document.getElementById('myDivHolder').appendChild(div);
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AkXTr/

Answer (score 4):

You get nothing in your HTML, because your HTML is on the server.

You get nothing in the DOM, because you haven't added the element to the DOM.

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to creating the element, you must insert it into the DOM. You can use the `appendChild()` method to add it to the end of a given parent element:

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id','testttttttt');

div.innerHTML='fjsoidfjiosdjfoi';

// Now, append it
document.getElementById('someOtherElement').appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll actually need to append it to something; I'm guessing `document.body` will do.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'testttttttt';
div.innerHTML = 'fjsoidfjiosdjfoi';​

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Make sure you do this when `document.body` actually exists, though, i.e. in a `load` event or inside the `body` element itself.

Answer (score 1):

You created the div correctly, just it hangs in nowhere. It needs to be inserted into the document, e.g. like

```
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id','testttttttt');
        div.innerHTML='fjsoidfjiosdjfoi';
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```